# How can I update the sdk through zip file?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, updates

I was updating the sdk in android studio, But due to unstable Internet It always gets interrupted and starts from beginning. I downloaded the zip file that was showing in the dialog box. 
Now I want to update the sdk through zip file.[image]

The link is https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r30.zip

Answer (score 1):

Open Android Stdio ,Go to File>project Structure>update the path of sdk(location to your new unzipped sdk).Thats it!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your appcompat dependency to

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+'
```